# properties of connect sets in plane

Tags: general-topology

If $A\subseteq\Bbb{R^2}$ is connect and is not single point,then proof $A\subseteq A^\prime$.and give counterexample that $$\\(cl(A))^°=A^°$$ 
is not true.note that $cl(A)$ is closure of $A$

Comment: Consider a punctured disc for the counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition has nothing to do with $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it holds in any $T_1$ space. If $x ∈ A \setminus A'$, then $x$ is an isolated point of $A$, so $\{x\}$ is open in $A$. And in $T_1$ space the singleton is also closed.